# Cannot connect to MS SQL RDS instance

Tags: networking, telnet, rds

I can´t Connect to my RDS MSSQL instance.

- The 'Public accessibility' is set to Yes
- the subnet goups are using 2 VPC subnets

  - subnet A: CIDR 10.70.2.0/28
  - subnet B: CIDR 10.70.2.16/28
    Both subnets has the 'Auto-assign IPv4' flag activated.
- The subnets have in rout table the internet-gateway set tho the 0.0.0.0
- The RDS security Group have the registry 'All TCP to 0.0.0.0/0'

Even with such configs the RDS instance don´t allow me to make a telnet connection.
I followed the steps from [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxFZt8MG2ss&t=38s).
End from [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connectivity-instance-subnet-vpc/).

But it still does not work for me.
A telnet form of an EC2 Instance is working fine.
I don´t know what to do any more.